# How to pnpm and Next.js in multi-stage docker file?

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, next.js, docker-multi-stage-build, pnpm

[The official Next.js Dockerfile example](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#docker-image) does not work if I switch `npm` to `pnpm`.

How should I modify that Dockerfile so that it remains multi-stage, but also uses `pnpm` instead of `npm`?

Comment: There is no `npm` in that [Dockerfile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile); it is using Yarn. What exactly have you changed, and what is the error you're experiencing? Please add necessary details in the questions. The change should be direct - `yarn build` to `pnpm run build`, `yarn` to `pnpm`, `yarn.lock` to `pnpm-lock.yaml`. What is causing issue? `pnpm` is just a package manager, it should not cause problems as such.

Comment: As @brc-dd mentioned, it's hard to tell if we don't know what's the error you're seeing. That being said, you may need to install `pnpm` within the Docker container before using it: `RUN npm install -g pnpm`.

Answer (score 20):

Another solution is installing pnpm using npm. When you install nodejs it comes with npm as the default package manager. So you can install pnpm using npm using the following command `npm install -g pnpm`

In the docker file it will be written as;

```
RUN npm install -g pnpm
```

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me is the following:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS base
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@7.4.1 --activate 
...
```

The above assumes that you're using either >=Node 16.9 or >=Node 14.19; that has the `corepack` command [built-in](https://github.com/nodejs/corepack).

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm a bit late, but this is what worked for me:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache curl \
    && curl -sL https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
```

Comment: This one may not install the correct version of pnpm

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the following:

```
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine3.16
RUN corepack enable
RUN corepack prepare pnpm@7.18.0 --activate
```